# Unable to click on the ticks of slider

Tags: wpf, slider

WPF-Slider: I am unable to click on the ticks of second slider (testOther) in which i am using very small values of scale, while it is working in first slider (testSlider). Can some body help me to solve the problem ?

```
<Slider Name="testSlider"  Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" Width="200" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
                    Value="50" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" 
                    TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="25" />

<Slider Name="testother" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" Width="200" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
                Value="0.5" Minimum="0" Maximum="1" 
                TickPlacement="BottomRight"  TickFrequency="0.25"></Slider>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

above solution of @lucassith is good,but there is a problem with this solution and that is you can't make the slider move to value in one click on tickbar. and this issue is solved in other thread. you can use IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" to solve it. Please refer to below link for further details.
[How do I make Slider move to value in one click on tick bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164979/how-do-i-make-slider-move-to-value-in-one-click-on-tick-bar/29165020#29165020)

Answer (score 3):

If you REALLY want to use 1/4th of the value you have to add LargeChange="0.25" property to your slider's markup. It should be like this

```
<Slider Name="testother" Margin="164,36,153,-36" Width="200" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
                Value="0.5" Minimum="0" Maximum="1" 
                TickPlacement="BottomRight"  TickFrequency="0.25" LargeChange="0.25"></Slider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why (it's a [double value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider.tickfrequency(v=vs.110).aspx) after all , but it seems like the scale is too small. It works fine if you go with integers:

```
<Slider Name="testother" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" Width="200" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
            Value="2" Minimum="0" Maximum="4" 
            TickPlacement="BottomRight"  TickFrequency="1"/>
```

So you could go with that and just take a 1/4th of the value :)

Comment: i already shared an example with large scales, but i need the slider with small scales due to my binding values. :)