# How do I make Slider move to value in one click on tick bar

Tags: wpf, slider

I am working on a slider, and below is the code:

```
<Slider Name="testother" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="200" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
            Value="0.5" Minimum="0" Maximum="1" 
            TickPlacement="BottomRight"  TickFrequency="0.25" LargeChange="0.25"></Slider>
```

[image]

when the slider is on extreme left,and we want to bring the slider to extreme right, it takes 3 clicks having slider navigate at every stop of the tick. the pointer should move quickly at one click.
Is there any way to solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need IsMoveToPointEnabled to be set to True to get this thing done!

```
<Slider IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
        Value="0.5"
        Minimum="0"
        Maximum="1" 
        TickPlacement="BottomRight"
        TickFrequency="0.25"
        IsMoveToPointEnabled="True"
        LargeChange="1"/>
```

You can still set small change in case you want to change slider values from keyboard

Comment: thanks for your help, but from your solution, there is a problem,now it will not stop on other clicks, like if i was on the extreme left, and click on 75%, it will not stop at 75% :-)

Comment: you then need IsMoveToPointEnabled="True"

Comment: glad it worked, you might wanna try n get rid of LargeChange it might not be needed anymore .. try it out!

Comment: now it is working without setting either "Large Change" or "Small change" property.

Comment: the same i was thinking :) Any way, thanks for your help

Comment: The properties that actually solve your solution are `TickFrequency`, `IsSnapToTickEnabled` and `IsMoveToPointEnabled`. there is no need for other properties to solve your question.